blender normal texture missing causing weird normals
recently I opened an old blender file that had no textures packed resources. therefore the 3d model had a normal map texture that was missing causing the model to have weird normals.
Strange thing is I like those normals (created by the missing texture) and I am seeking ways to recreate them.
anyone know how?

if you have lost the original image and the original high poly you need to recreate a high poly and sculpt on it to then bake again and recreate a normal map

sorry I asked the question wrong. I like the normals the model has I just don't know how to define this state. my model has a normal material with a normal map node that goes into an image texture THAT HAS NO IMAGE. how do i recreate this AS a normal map?

Hello could you please share your file or at least show some pictures?

hey, please see picture above. pic on the left is the first one and is the standard. the pic on the right is the second and is the desired one. notice the one on the right does not have an actual normal map and yet its normals are different. WHY?

The image is missing, so it's like plugging a (hex) FF00FF pink in the Normal Map

I guess plugging an empty Image Texture node is like plugging a (hex FF00FF) pink color into the Normal Map, as empty Image Texture nodes emit pink, so you can simply plug an Input > RGB node with a (hex FF00FF) pink color:


thank you greatly! never knew the exact color of the missing texture. how did you find it?

With the eyedropper
